# Having trouble with a database query using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm quite stuck in my programming when I query some of my data,

I want to sort my database student to arrange by year I did use order by year in SQL Server like this:

```
select *   
from Student 
where year >=1 and year <= 4 
order by year;
```

The code seems to work but when I query my data in the aspx.cs code behind, the program alerts me with an error.

This is my aspx code behind sample:

```
string yearfrom = (this.YearFrom.Value);
string yearto = (this.YearTo.Value);

if(yearfrom != "yearfrom1" && yearto != "yearto2")
{
   query = "select * from student where year >= '" + yearfrom + "' and year <= '" + yearto + "order by year'";
}
```

The query I used in here doesn't seem to work, I don't know why.

Comment: You're putting quotes around what I assume is suppose to be an integer value, thus making the DB treat it as a string.  In general it would be better to parse the values and then use parameters to avoid possible sql injection.  You also put the end quote after the order by thus making it part of the string instead of part of the sql statement.

Comment: Might be due to the use of `'` around the parameters.

Comment: Add space just before the word order.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Your code is a textbook example of sql injection. Do yourself a favor and parameterize your queries immediately if not sooner. You also should use column names in your code instead of select *. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution the answer post by @Steve is also correct.

```
if(yearfrom != "yearfrom1" && yearto != "yearto2")
{
   query = @"select * from student 
             where [year] >= @from and [year] <= @to 
             order by [year]";
}
```

this one is also applicable posted by @DeepakPawar a minute ago.

```
query = "select * from student where year >= " + yearfrom + " and year <= " + yearto + " order by year";
```

thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: You fixed the error but there is a white elephant standing in the corner, his name is sql injection. YOU NEED TO FIX THAT!!!

Comment: I need to research about sql injection further more, it says that the only way to protect a website from sql injection attacks is to use sql parameters, right? This is just a school project not a company so its not very classified.

Comment: Then since you are still in school it isn't too late to learn to do this correctly. Yes you should use parameters. The injection vulnerability is not limited to websites, you should always parameterize your queries regardless of the technology.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion sir, I'll study about that and improve my programming skills.